# Got error when generating signed apk I will search out many solutions but stiil can't able to fix it

Tags: android, android-proguard

Proguard files as

```
     -keepnames class org.apache.** {*;}
     -keep public class org.apache.** {*;}
     -dontwarn android.support.v4.**
     -keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
     -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

build.gradle

```
       buildTypes {
       release {


        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-project.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
    }
    flavor2 {
        proguardFile 'flavor2-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
```

Logcat  will give   following  error

```
 Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.FileNotFoundException:    C:\Users\hp-\Desktop\GoFinder2\app\flavor2-rules.pro (The system cannot find   the file specified)
 :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForFlavor2Release FAILED
 Error:Execution failed for task     ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForFlavor2Release'.
```

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\hp-\Desktop\GoFinder2\app\flavor2-rules.pro (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: Does the file `flavor2-rules.pro` exist?

Comment: No there is not any flavor2-rules.pro

Comment: If the flavor2-rules.pro files exists, what is it's path because the Android build is not finding it where it is expected

Comment: Actually i don't know anything  I just copy  proguad rules from android developer site . Can you tell what should I do now

Comment: @Ishwinder Each product flavor must have its own proguard rules.

Comment: Ok I will  remove flavor2 rules and  now  generate apk  succesfully but it can't open show the error        Error: Activity class does not exist.
Can you help me for this?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the missing file `flavor2-rules.pro` you will most likely also need to use a different default ProGuard configuration file. Instead of using this:

```
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-project.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

you should better use this:

```
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                  'proguard-project.txt'
```

Assuming that your actual rules are in a file `proguard-project.txt`, located in your application root directory.

Comment: Thanks  for help , I already  do that and    generated the signed apk which runs successfully .

Comment: In you last comment you mentioned that the app does not run correctly: Activity class does not exist, thus I added the additional suggestion to include the proper default rules.